# can't start play 2.2 on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-hosting, port-80

I am trying to deploy my project on port 80 by using

```
play start 80
play "start 80"
play "start -Dhttp.port=8080"
```

It's giving me this error:

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:80
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$10.apply(NettyServer.scala:134)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$10.apply(NettyServer.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
```

I found a simmilar question here

[can't start play! server on ec2 (play! framework)](https://serverfault.com/questions/477473/cant-start-play-server-on-ec2-play-framework)

but the answer `sudo play start 80` gives me

```
sudo: play: command not found
```

Am I missing anything?

UPDATE:
i also tried

```
sudo /home/ubuntu/play-2.2.0/play start 80
```

it doesn't give the error, but still browser saying **can't establish a connection to the server at mydomain** , where `play "start 8080"` works perfectly

[image]

---

```
    sudo netstat -nlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57983           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      950/beam        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      799/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      910/epmd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      645/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      8273/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      950/beam        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      645/sshd        
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6142     266/udevd           /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5941     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7577     756/acpid           /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8113     799/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7399     664/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

Comment: Do `which play` as non-sudo user to see where the binary is, then run it explicitly, like `sudo /usr/bin/play start 80`.

Comment: @ceejayoz i tried, no error occours but still i am unable to connect

Comment: Did you open port 80 in EC2's security groups as well as any firewalls you have locally?

Comment: @ceejayoz port 80 is open already, but what about any firewall? i didnt see any firewall setting in ec2

Comment: Did you open port 80 in your EC2 security group ?

Comment: @Iain yes, port 80 is open in my ec2 security group

Comment: Can you please post output of  netstat -tunlep | grep LISTEN

Comment: I've no idea, I don't even know what play is. If you're in that much need of help the reach fr your cheque book.

Comment: @VaibhavPanmand updated my question, please have a look

Comment: i tried all stuffs that all you person says and finally it runs, thanks to all of you

Comment: can you try with -- sudo PATH_TO_PLAY/play -Dhttp.port=80  start

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for your comment , it helps me, you can put it as a answer,`sudo /home/ubuntu/play-2.2.0/play "start 80"` helps me, i get this path by `which play`